# Display feet decimals in feet and inches (javascript)

Tags: javascript, decimal

Original question:
*this bit of javascript code will convert centimeters to feet.
But the feet are displayed as decimals, I would like it to display as 5'10 instead of 5.83.*

**SOLUTION:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function start(){
document.getElementById('hauteur_cm').onmouseup=function() {
if(isNaN(this.value)) {
   alert('numbers only!!');
   document.getElementById('hauteur_cm').value='';
   document.getElementById('hauteur_pieds').value='';
   return;
 }
var realFeet = this.value*0.03280839895;
var feet = Math.floor(realFeet);
var inches = Math.round((realFeet - feet) * 12);
var text = feet + "'" + inches + '"';
   document.getElementById('hauteur_pieds').value=text;
  }
 }
if(window.addEventListener){
   window.addEventListener('load',start,false);
 }
else {
if(window.attachEvent){
   window.attachEvent('onload',start);
  }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can split the decimal feet value into feet and inches like this:

```
var realFeet = 5.83;

var feet = Math.floor(realFeet);
var inches = Math.round((realFeet - feet) * 12);
```

Then you can put them together in any format you like:

```
var text = feet + "'" + inches + '"';
```

Comment: pardon me for being such a javascript simpleton but how can I set realFeet to the converted value of "hauteur_pieds" (from code above) and then send the var text to the element ID "hauteur_pieds"? Much appreciated.

Comment: @date: First var realFeet = this.value*0.03280839895; then do the conversion and finally use document.getElementById('hauteur_pieds').value = text;

Answer (score 2):

```
function feetAndInches(decimal) {
  return Math.floor(decimal) +
    "'" +
    (12 * (decimal - Math.floor(decimal))) +
    '"';
}
```